Привязка static meshes в blueprint spline к поверности static meshes в landscape spline
Я новичок в UE 5. У меня есть landscape spline с static mesh внутри. К поверхности static meshes этого landscape spline мне нужно привязать blueprint spline, чтобы static mesh, которые генерируются в blueprint spline с помощью PCG были расположены на static meshes в lanscape spline. Я понимаю, что возможно есть другие варианты, но по другому сделать то, что я делаю, не представляю как.
Очень прошу помочь мне с этим.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //Можете,пожалуйста, уточнить, как именно вы интегрировали static mesh в landscape spline? И что вы подразумеваете под привязкой blueprint spline к поверхности этих мешей? Было бы полезно, если бы вы добавили больше деталей или пример кода.
